# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="events_table"]"}

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

Need to scrape a table from https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/billions/events. There is a link on the website to download the table but downloaded file does not have Summary column.
Tried  to use following code to scrape the table:

```
url = 'https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/access/billions/events'
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
df=pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_id("events_table").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
```

but got error

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="events_table"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.61)
```

while I manually checked the chrome version on my mac is  `100.0.4896.127`.

inspect the table component, found the table id is `events_table`

[image]

Comment: I do not see `events_table` id on the first web page? where is it on the application?

Answer (score 1):

Is using `find_element_by_id` a must or is using `find_element_by_xpath` fine by you? Because this works if you were to use `find_element_by_xpath` and provide the id:

```
df=pd.read_html(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="events-table"]').get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
```

Result:

```
                                                 Event  ... Deaths
0                                Western Wildfires2021  ...      8
1                   Western Drought and Heat Wave2021†  ...    229
2    Midwest Derecho and Tornado OutbreakDecember 2...  ...      1
3    Southeast, Central Tornado OutbreakDecember 2021†  ...     93
4                    Hurricane NicholasSeptember 2021†  ...      0
..                                                 ...  ...    ...
318  Severe Storms, Flash Floods, Hail, TornadoesMa...  ...     20
319                         Florida FreezeJanuary 1981  ...      0
320  Central/ Eastern Drought/ Heat WaveSummer-Fall...  ...   1260
321                         Hurricane AllenAugust 1980  ...     13
322      Southern Severe Storms and FloodingApril 1980  ...      7
```